# relation matching after relation extraction

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I have the following concepts.

chief accepted proposal,
chief rejected proposal,
proposal was deferred
...
proposal accepted consensus,
no consensus proposal rejected.

I want to match instances in other sentences which share the same concept/meaning. For instance, other sentences where the "proposal was accepted".

I have researched on the topic relation extraction. However, i would like to use these retrieved relations to match relations in other sentences.

I am using string matching at the moment but it not giving desired result.

Meaningful capture:
"the revised proposal was accepted by chief at seminar."

Inaccurate captures:
But also inaccurate captures happen which don't mean the same thing : same words also exist in these sentences and its not same meaning.

"Chief, i 'm particularly interested in hearing your opinion about the following three issues : should this proposal be accepted at all . ."

"Chief said, i will retract the proposal, because is too late for me.is the proposal accepted ? ."

"hi chief, should this proposal be accepted at all . ."

I was thinking of using relationship extraction and then match it to the relationships in these sentences. Is there a way to do relationship matching after relation extraction?  I cant find any reference to relationship matching on the web.

Comment: plz provide more details - what is the string matching method you are using, and how are you using it?

Comment: I am using keyword matching in sentence using the words "chief" "accept" and "proposal". I am checking to see if all of these words exist in the sentence.

Comment: this requires a much more complicated pipeline to work. First thing that comes in mind is to use dependency parsing to get dependencies like nsubj(chief,accept), and nobj(accept, proposal). You will probably need to link a chain of these dependencies to find certain types of dependencies that help you to distinguish between correct/incorrect co-occurrences of these words (mainly based on their grammatical rule). For dependecy parser you can use stanford parser: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Comment: Thank you user3639557, Once I hae found those dependencies, is there a way to distinguish dependencies?

Comment: Unfortunate I don't. It completely depends on the sentence but probably there are certain types of dependencies that are more key to your task (i.e. nsubj, nobj, ... ). I suggest running a parser over some text and for each sentence looking at the dependencies. I am sure you will get a better idea about the important types of dependencies once you have the parser running.